# No module named appengine.ext for get client lib java create

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create get client lib java and when i run this code

```
sudo python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle src.service.moDbile_api.MobileApi
```

it gave me an error

```
valid SDK root.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 59, in <module>
    import _endpointscfg_setup  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/var/www/html/salesmanagement/SalesManagement/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 107, in <module>
    _SetupPaths()
  File "/var/www/html/salesmanagement/SalesManagement/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 103, in _SetupPaths
    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

The `google.appengine.ext` module only exists when running your script in the [App Engine First Generation (Python 2.7) runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/).